# Integrity constraint violation, foreign key constraint fails

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, constraints, entity-relationship

I have 3 entity : Invoice, InvoiceItemService, Asset.

First, I create an Invoice and an InvoiceItemService, and I link them together with a ManyToOne relation on InvoiceItemService side (so InvoiceItemService is the owner side).

Then, I can create an Asset, from the Invoice object. An asset is kind of a copy of an Invoice, with a negative total. When I create an Asset, I link the Invoice's InvoiceItemService to the Asset too, with a ManyToOne relation between InvoiceItemService and Asset.

When I delete an Invoice, everything works fine, Invoice, Asset and InvoiceItemService are deleted with a cascade={"remove"} option.

When I delete an Asset, I would like only the asset to be deleted. But I get this foreign key error.

Here are my entities :

```
class Invoice
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\Asset", mappedBy="invoice", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    protected $assets;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\InvoiceItemService", mappedBy="invoice", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $services;
}

class Asset
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\Invoice", inversedBy="assets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Exclude
     */
    protected $invoice;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\InvoiceItemService", mappedBy="asset")
     */
    protected $services;
}

class InvoiceItemService extends InvoiceItem
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\Invoice", inversedBy="services")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @Type("Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\Invoice")
     * @Exclude
     */
    protected $invoice;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\Asset", inversedBy="services")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     * @Type("Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\Asset")
     * @Exclude
     */
    protected $asset;
}
```

Comment: Are there other entities that might rely on an `Asset` for a foreign key? Your error may be entirely unrelated to the relationship between these three you posted here.

Comment: i'm pretty sure the problem is here, according to the SQL error : ```a foreign key constraint fails (`evotest`.`sf_invoices_items_services`, CONSTRAINT `FK_38F5C7765DA1941` FOREIGN KEY (`asset_id`) REFERENCES `sf_assets` (`id`)) ``` Actually, i would need a doctrine option to set `asset_id` to NULL in InvoiceItemService, when an asset is deleted. tried `@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")` in InvoiceItemService#asset property, but error still there

Comment: It's up to you to remove any InvoiceItemService items that reference the asset.  The D2 delete cascade is not smart enough to go back upstream and delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cerad mentioned in the comments above, you'll need to implement this behavior yourself.

Since you'll need access to the entity manager, you can't do this with a simple lifecycle callback on the Asset entity itself. Instead, you'll need to register a service to listen for the event and perform the action at that point.

Example implementation

**app/config.yml**

```
services:
    your.bundle.association.manager:
        class: Your\Bundle\Model\AssociationManager
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preRemove }
```

And then, the service class itself (unstested - might have bugs)

```
namespace Your\Bundle\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Your\Bundle\Entity\Asset;

class AssociationManager
{
  public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
  {
    if ($entity instanceof Asset)
    {
      $this->removeAssetAssociations($asset, $args->getEntityManager());
      return;
    }
  }

  protected function removeAssetAssociations(Asset $asset, EntityManager $em)
  {
    foreach ($asset->getServices() as $invoiceItemService)
    {
      $invoiceItemService->asset = null;
      $em->persist($invoiceItemService);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok great. The key was to understand I had to unset these relationships manually. I already had an event listener set up on Asset removal, so it was piece of cake. Actually, I only use your `foreach()` part, everything else was already coded. day after day, i find doctrine more and more amazing, but I think I found here one of its limitations, seems Doctrine can't automatically deal with relationship detachments. Anyway, thank you for your reply. Thanks to Cerad too. +1 for both of you.